# How to determine if custom menu is active?

Tags: theme-development, menus

My theme registers custom menus with this function:

```
function nav_menus() {
    if ( function_exists( 'register_nav_menus' ) ) {
      register_nav_menus(
        array('main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu' ), 'sub-menu' => __( 'Sub Menu' ))
      );
    }
}
```

I need to place code into my sidebar, that checks to see if the "main-menu" is active - for example, has a menu assigned to the "Main Menu" theme location.

Anyone know how to test for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the function `has_nav_menu('main-menu')`. See the WordPress Codex [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu).

Answer (score 2):

Use has_nav_menu:

> Returns boolean Whether a registered nav menu location has a menu assigned(true) or not(false).

```
<?php $menu=has_nav_menu( $location ); ?>
```

Reference: [has_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_nav_menu)